# Print file age in seconds using Python

Tags: python, file

I need my script to download a new file, if the old one is old enough. I set the maximum age of file in seconds. So that I would get back on track with my script writing I need example code, where file age is printed out in seconds.

Comment: We will be happy to help you correct a problem in your existing code. We will not, in most cases, write the code for you.

Comment: Well, I certainly can't agree with you. I think that that giving examples is not writing the code for me. And also, if you say that what I am asking is you writing code for me, then there is loads of code wrote for other people.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This shows how to find a file's (or directory's) last modification time:

Here are the number of seconds since the Epoch, using [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
import os
st=os.stat('/tmp')    
mtime=st.st_mtime
print(mtime)
# 1325704746.52
```

Or, equivalently, using [os.path.getmtime](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime):

```
print(os.path.getmtime('/tmp'))
# 1325704746.52
```

If you want a [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object:

```
import datetime         
print("mdatetime = {}".format(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)))
# mdatetime = 2012-01-04 14:19:06.523398
```

Or a formated string using [time.ctime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.ctime)

```
import stat
print("last accessed => {}".format(time.ctime(st[stat.ST_ATIME])))
# last accessed => Wed Jan  4 14:09:55 2012
print("last modified => {}".format(time.ctime(st[stat.ST_MTIME])))
# last modified => Wed Jan  4 14:19:06 2012
print("last changed => {}".format(time.ctime(st[stat.ST_CTIME])))
# last changed => Wed Jan  4 14:19:06 2012
```

Although I didn't show it, there are equivalents for finding the access time and change time for all these methods. Just follow the links and search for "atime" or "ctime".

Comment: Here's my solution: `import os import time st=os.stat(Filename)
    Age=(time.time()-st.st_mtime)
    print Age`

Answer (score 42):

Another approach (I know I wasn't the first answer but here goes anyway):

```
import time, os, stat

def file_age_in_seconds(pathname):
    return time.time() - os.stat(pathname)[stat.ST_MTIME]
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer does not actually answer the question, it just gives the  answer for last modification time.  For getting the file age in seconds, minutes or hour you can do this.

```
import os, time

def file_age(filepath):
    return time.time() - os.path.getmtime(filepath)

seconds = file_age('myFile.txt') # 7200 seconds
minutes = int(seconds) / 60 # 120 minutes
hours = minutes / 60 # 2 hours
```

Answer (score 3):

Use stat.M_TIME to get the last modified time and subtract it from the current time.

http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import os, time 

def file_age_in_seconds(filename): 
    try: 
        return int(time.time() - os.path.getmtime(filename)) 
    except: 
        #on any failure condition 
        return -1  
 
filename = "/tmp/foobar.txt" 

print(file_age_in_seconds(filename))   #prints -1 
f = open(filename, 'w') 
f.write("this is a line") 
f.close()

print(file_age_in_seconds(filename))   #prints 0 
time.sleep(4.2) 
print(file_age_in_seconds(filename))   #prints 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do in days, can be modified for seconds also:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import datetime
from datetime import date

t1 = os.path.getctime("<filename>")

now = datetime.datetime.now()

Y1 = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t1)).strftime('%Y'))
M1 = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t1)).strftime('%m'))
D1 = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t1)).strftime('%d'))

date1 = date(Y1, M1, D1)

Y2 = int(now.strftime('%Y'))
M2 = int(now.strftime('%m'))
D2 = int(now.strftime('%d'))

date2 = date(Y2, M2, D2)

diff = date2 - date1

days = diff.days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using `OS` and `datetime` lib in python:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def fileAgeInSeconds(directory, filename):
    file = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        stat = os.stat(file)
        try:
            creation_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_birthtime)
        except AttributeError:
            creation_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(stat.st_mtime)
        curret_time = datetime.now()
        duration = curret_time - creation_time
        duration_in_s = duration.total_seconds()
        return duration_in_s
    else:
        print('%s File not found' % file)
        return 100000
```

#Calling the function

```
dir=/tmp/
fileAgeInSeconds(dir,'test.txt')
```